# Search whether a document exists in a JSON API, not by primary identifier

Tags: api, rest, json-api

I am building a JSON API and have a `user` resource. A `user` has `id` as its primary identifier and some other fields: `facebook_id`, `linkedin_id` and so on.

I need to check whether a certain `user` exists, only by having one of the other fields (e.g.: `facebook_id`). I cannot use `/users/<id>` and check whether it returns a `404` because I don't have the primary identifier.

I thought about using a `/users/exists?<field>=<value>`, but I'm not sure whether this is the correct approach with JSON API.

My questions are, what endpoint should I create, what code should it return in case the document exists or not, and what body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the facebook id as a parameter in the query string, something like:

```
GET /users?facebookId=12345
```

if the http status code response is 200 then the user does exist and the content is an user resource, for example:

```
/users?facebookId={fb_id}:
    get:
      summary: ...
      description: ...
      parameters:
        - name: fb_id
          in: path
          required: true
          type: integer
      responses:
        "200":
          description: ...
          schema: 
            $ref: '#/definitions/userResource'
```

Comment: Okay, but if it doesn't exist, a request to `/users` should also respond with `200` but return an empty list. Or am I wrong?

Comment: According to the [JSON API reference](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching) you have to return a 404 status

Comment: It's still not clear, the reference only states about trying to fetch an individual resource. It doesn't make sense to return a 404 for a search on a collection - it will always return something, worst, an empty array.

Comment: The reference also states about collections, you can either return an 200 status code with a payload and an empty array for the data attribute or a 403 status code with an empty response